# Usage of useRef with debounce function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debouncing

I have the following setup in a react component where I have used the debounce function from [throttle-debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle-debounce#debounce) package to log the input value for testing ( actually calling an API to fetch data ).

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import debounce from 'throttle-debounce/debounce';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [localSearchQuery, setLocalSearchQuery] = useState('');
  
  const setSearchQueryInParams = debounce(2000, value => console.log(value))

  const setSearchQuery = value => {
    setLocalSearchQuery(value);
    setSearchQueryInParams(value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Input
        value={localSearchQuery}
        onChange={setSearchQuery}
      />;
    </>
  );
};
```

But, it's not working as expected. If I type `hello` in the input box, I get the following output in console:

```
h
he
hel
hell
hello
```

However, if I wrap the debounce function with useRef, it works as expected

```js
const setSearchQueryInParams = useRef(debounce(2000, value => console.log(value))).current
```

```js
Input: hello
Output in console: hello
```

My question is, why the debounce function is not working without useRef and how useRef is functioning here to get the desired output?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use `useCallback`, with an empty dependency array, nstead of `useRef`:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import debounce from 'throttle-debounce/debounce';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [localSearchQuery, setLocalSearchQuery] = useState('');
  
  const setSearchQueryInParams = useCallback(debounce(2000, value => console.log(value)), []);

  const setSearchQuery = value => {
    setLocalSearchQuery(value);
    setSearchQueryInParams(value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Input
        value={localSearchQuery}
        onChange={setSearchQuery}
      />;
    </>
  );
};
```

The reason is that calling `debounce` always returns a new function, so you need to store that function across rerenders.

Without that, it has no memory of the `setTimeout`s it internally calls so it can't use them to debounce properly.

Comment: In the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle-debounce#debounce) they didn't use the useCallback with debounce but it still showed correct output.

In my case, is it because when the input value changes, it rerenders the component and loose track of the previous setTimeout and that's why we need to use useCallback to get the correct behaviour?

Comment: In their documentation, they didn't use `useCallback`... because they're not using React at all in those examples. Their code is all vanilla (except for their library) and all variables are in the global context. In your app, rerendering will make the app lose track of that `debounce`, and `useCallback` allows you to store that value across multiple rerenders.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helps. Will it make a difference If we use `useRef` instead of `useCallback`?